# How to set "back" button goto homecontroller after open viewcontroller of push notification in ios?

Tags: swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've define desire viewController when tap push notification in IOS 11.

But when i click "back" button, it's not going anywhere because there isn't any stack made. How to define "back" button as homecontroller->root viewcontroller after tap push notification ?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        let viewController = InboxController()
        
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```